# Declare Instance variables in django-formtools SessionWizardView

Tags: python, django, django-formtools

Using SessionWizardView, I want to declare Instance variables, that persist between steps. However, they are not persistent, when using:

`def __init__(self): self.variable = {}`

Answer (score -1):

```py
class YourClass:
    class_variable = None

    def __init__(self):
        if YourClass.class_variable is None:
            YourClass.class_variable = "default value"
        self.instance_variable = YourClass.class_variable

instance1 = YourClass()
print("instance1>>",instance1.variable)
instance2 = YourClass()
print("instance2>>",instance2.variable)
```

```
>>> instance1>> default value
>>> instance2>> default value
```

Comment: This does not work with SessionWizardView. I get a TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'initial_dict'